# How can I make mpv show the duration counter constantly?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, media-player, mpv

I use the mpv video player in Linux. With the keys <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, I can see the duration of the video I am watching.

How can I set mpv to show the duration all the time (without the need of pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) ?

Answer (score 13):

Aside from the configuration <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> toggles duration display in the player.

Answer (score 10):

Check [MPV documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#osd). You can use option: `--osd-level=2`. Or write into config file (location: `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`):

```
# Show duration by default.
osd-level=2
```